# How to switch Key and Values in Dictionary where value might be Null

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a `dictionary<string,string>` with the following values

```
"abc","Message 1" 
"def","Message 1" 
"ghi","Message 2" 
"jkl","Message 1" 
"mno","Message 2" 
"pqr","Message 3"
```

Ultimately I'm trying to group this dictionary by Message.

What I would like to do is loop through this new dictionary and be able to output something like this:

```
abc, def, jkl : Message 1
ghi, mno : Message 2
prq : Message 3
```

I'm trying to build another object so I can loop through it, but the `ToDictionary()` is giving me issues:

```
var oD = messageDictionary.GroupBy(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(g=>g.Key,g=>g.ToString());
```

**The issue** in this example is when the Value part it is `NULL`. Because then the `ToDictionary` throws a `NullReferenceException`. How can I solve it?

I've also tried just creating a new dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> newDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
newDictionary = messageDictionary.GroupBy(x => x.Value);
```

This has an conversion issue.

Maybe there is a better way then using a dictionary?  I just thought it would be easier using a dictionary.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll stick to the dictionary because you are almost there and this will help you understand what you missed.

The problem is in the `Value` of the `dictionary` - You want to select all the `item.Key` (the original's dictionary's keys) and have that `IEnumerable` as the value of your new dictionary.

Then you can print it joining the new "values" using `string.Join`

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "abc", "Message 1" },
    { "def", "Message 1" },
    { "ghi", "Message 2" },
    { "jkl", "Message 1" },
    { "mno", "Message 2" },
    { "pqr", "Message 3" },
    { "aaa", null }
};

var result = values.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
                   // In this line the g.Key refers to the `Key` of the IGrouping and not
                   // of the original dictionary. 
                   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key ?? string.Empty, 
                                 // However, on this line each `item` is of the type 
                                 // KeyValuePair and the `.Key` refers to the original's 
                                 // dictionary's key
                                 g => g.Select(item => item.Key).ToList())
                                 //Or: string.Join(", ", g.Select(item => item.Key))
                   .ToList();

foreach (var pair in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", string.Join(", ", pair.Value), pair.Key);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that is not supposed to be .ToDictionary(g => g.Value,   ?

Comment: What if one of the entries in the original dictionary was NULL?  i.e. {"xyz",}  How would handle that?

Comment: @Paparazzi - No because it is the `Key` of the IGrouping (which is the `Value` of the original dictionary) and not the dictionary's key

Comment: @webdad3 - checking it now

Comment: @webdad3 - Indeed in a dictionary the key cannot be null - Added a fix

Comment: @GiladGreen - I think I got it working.  Thanks for the code and the comments.  They helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
                                                { "abc","Message 1" },
                                                {"def","Message 1" },
                                                {"ghi","Message 2"} ,
                                                {"jkl","Message 1"} ,
                                                {"mno","Message 2"} ,
                                                {"pqr","Message 3"}
                                                };
            var temp = myDict.GroupBy(c => c.Value);
            foreach (var i in temp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.Key);
                foreach (var k in i)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", k.Key);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("=============");

            }
```

Output : 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Aggregate method to append the keys together like this:

```
var oD = messageDictionary.GroupBy(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(v => v.Value).Aggregate((a, c) => a + ',' + c))
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a multimap (a dictionary where the "value" is a collection) is exactly [ToLookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211(v=vs.110).aspx) extension's job.

It also nicely handle null keys (added an example and changed the formatting a little to reflect that).

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "abc", "Message 1" },
    { "def", "Message 1" },
    { "ghi", "Message 2" },
    { "jkl", "Message 1" },
    { "mno", "Message 2" },
    { "pqr", "Message 3" }
    { "stu", null },
};

// we create a lookup where the key is the value and it's values are the keys
var valueLookup = values.ToLookup (kvp => kvp.Value, kvp => kvp.Key);

foreach (var valueGroup in valueLookup)
{
    // valueGroup has type IGrouping<string, string>
    // which implements IEnumerable<string>
    // it allows it to be used by string.Join directly
    Console.WriteLine ($"{string.Join (", ", valueGroup)}: [{valueGroup.Key}]");
}
```

> ### Output :
>
> abc, def, jkl: [Message 1]
>   ghi, mno: [Message 2]
>   pqr: [Message 3]
>   stu: []